# Why random.shuffle(list(range(n))) works, but random.shuffle(range(n)) does not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, iterator

When, in Python 3, using `random` module `random.shuffle(list(range(n)))` works, but `random.shuffle(range(n))` does not.

Why is it so?

When I type `type(range(n))` it returns `range`.

Comment: Which language is your question about?

Comment: Your question is not true as written.  Entering `random.shuffle(list(range(n)))` does **not** work, because `random.shuffle` works in-place and doesn't return anything. Applying it to an item dynamically created as an argument won't yield any visible result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3's `range` now returns an range-object (beeing an **immutable sequence**) and not a list (like Python 2)!

A [range-object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) (besides other differences) does not support item assignment, which is the error you observe (probably):

```
File ".../random.py", line 272, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment
```

The line 272 is the pythonic-way of swapping two variables in python, which is a common operation in most shuffle algorithms (like Fisher-Yates).

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) also mentions this (if you want to shuffle sequences):

> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use sample(x, k=len(x)) instead

So this will work (and is equivalent given the task of shuffling):

```
shuffled_list = random.sample(range(n), k=n)
```

Your approach of creating a list first is also fine, if you can afford the memory/time needed to do that.